# deep cloning a typed array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, clone, typed-arrays

Trying to deep clone an array buffer (i.e, pass by value not by reference)

```
const deepClone = (buf) => {
    uint32 = new Uint32Array(buf);
    let newBuf = new ArrayBuffer(buf.byteLength);
    let uint32new = new Uint32Array(newBuf);

    //  This works fine
    uint32.forEach((el, i) => {
        uint32new[i] = el;
    });

    //  but this doesn't
    uint32new = uint32.map((el) => {return el});

    //  neither does this
    uint32new = [...uint32];

    return newBuf;
};
```

The latter 2 merely return an empty (0's) buffer

why?

Comment: `uint32new = ...` overwrites the variable, and does not write to the structure the variable currently holds. As such, you create a new typed array with e.g. `uint32.map((el) => {return el});`, which however isn't returned, and has no relation to `newBuf`. All that aside, i'd suggest you look at [ArrayBuffer.prototype.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer/slice), which makes a direct copy much shorter code-wise (and has higher chances of heavy optimization engine-side).

Comment: `uint32new =  uint32.slice()` or `uint32new = uint32.slice(0)` still produce an empty buffer

Comment: `const deepClone = buf => buf.slice(0);`, but then it imho becomes obvious, that the utility function you are trying to implement already exists as a native.

Comment: You are still overwriting a variable, which you are never returning - and has no effect on `newBuf` at all. You could e.g. `return uint32.map((el) => {return el}).buffer;`, a new buffer is already created in the `map`-call. As a note, `[...uint32]` will be an array, not a `TypedArray` or `ArrayBuffer`, just to at least touch your second example.

Comment: **do** `const deepClone = buf => Uint32Array.from(buf);`